# No internet but LAN works- IPv6?

Tags: networking, lan, wan

I have been having a problem lately where certain computers on my corporate network suddenly lose Internet connectivity, and I have resolved this by assigning a static ip, deleting the lease, then putting it back in DHCP mode. The other way I have resolved it is by in checking the binding box for IPv6 in the properties for the network adaptor. One time, pinging the computer's IPv4 address fixed it. This issue affects clients running XP, 7, 8, and Gentoo Linux. I can ping clients in various subnets of my LAN, which are in physically different locations, but cannot ping hosts on the Internet, even by IP address. We have no IPv6 infrastructure configured and most of our clients are XP/7. We have an older firewall- it's an old Cisco ASA5505. Could this be causing the problem, and if so can anyone recommend what settings would be likely to cause the issue? We are also using a Barracuda spam av filter and a Barracuda content filter, both of which are a little over three years old. Let me know if you have solutions for this problem. Thanks!

Comment: have you check if you nat table was full when the error occurred ?

Comment: No- where do I go for that? I use ASDM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was the firewall was license-restricted to 50 clients. Bought the unlimited upgrade and the problem is now resolved.